# PHP failing to write the same file multiple times if file is located in a subdirectory

Tags: php

I have three functions, basically doing the same thing (I know I can easily convert them to one function, but at the moment they must stay three).

The functions are similar to this one:

```
function setFlag($user_id, $flag)
{
    $file = $user_id . '_general_info.json';
    $recoveredData = file_get_contents($file);
    $recoveredArray = json_decode($recoveredData, true);
    $recoveredArray['isActive'] = $flag;
    $serializedData = json_encode($recoveredArray);
    file_put_contents($file, $serializedData, LOCK_EX);
}
```

so, they open the SAME file, get/decode its contents (JSON), add/update one of the JSON keys, save the file again.

The only difference between the functions is the JSON key they add or update.

Sometimes I have to call the functions one after another: anything works absolutely fine.

But if, in the first line of the function, I change the file path to a **subdirectory**, this way:

```
__DIR__ ."/". $user_id ."/". $user_id."_general_info.json"
```

for some reason only the latest key is added or updated into the file.
So, for example, if I call:

```
A();
B();
C();
```

it is like I only called `C()`.
If I comment out `C()`, the file doesn't write the key saved by `A` and writes the key `B` saves instead.

I suppose (even if at the moment I'm not sure) this has something to do with the fact that the code opens the same file multiple times.

But why in the current directory anything works fine and inside a subdirectory it fails?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you changed all 3 functions to use the new subdirectory?

Comment: Did you check your read / write permissions on the new directory?

Comment: I would be tempted,whereever the file is located, to use `flock()` to lock the file before opening it, then `LOCK->open->read->decode->change>encode>write>UNLOCK`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: absolutely sure

Comment: @oguzhancerit: permissions are set to 705

Comment: Is it one process that calls these functions or could they be called on the same user at the same time by seperate processes

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I am tempted too

Comment: @LifeafterGuest The problem could be the locked files. First your A() function opens the file to write and locked, then B(), last C(). Locked file by C() only unlocked by C() because of this reason your A() and B() function throws an error. Please look your error_log or update your environment to print errors.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: basically it is one process

Comment: @oguzhancerit: I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: Then I think the locking we both think is a good idea would probably solve this issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly: ok, but WHY in the current directory I see no issues?

Comment: Do thes funcs always get called in the same order? is C always the last called? Is it always the output from C that overwrite A and B

Comment: @RiggsFolly: the latest function called is the function that writes the content. If you remove the function C, you find B correctly wrote the file. If you remove B too, you find A correctly writes the file.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample;

1. A() function opens and locked the file
2. B() function opens and locked the file
3. C() function opens and locked the file

Locked file by C() function, only unlock by the C() function. While C() function updates the file, A() and B() function throws a warning. If your environment status is production, you can not see the warning. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param/22662582#22662582) to change environment in development process.

Please take a look your error_log file and add some conditions to your code like if the file is locked or not.

Comment: I'm ok with this explanation: basically it is the same thing I think. But WHY in the current directory I see no issue?

Comment: @LifeafterGuest I think,  `__DIR__` is the problem. If you add `__DIR__` in the first step you will facing with the same error.